# why thymeleaf get URL residual "/user/edit"?

Tags: java, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBWdP.png)

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Photo:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="file" id="fileImage" name="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg">
                    <img alt="Photos preview" th:src="@{${user.photosImagePath}}" id="thumbnail" width="100" height="110">                                  
                </div>
            </div>  


@Transient
public String getPhotosImagePath() {
    if(id == null || photos == null) return "/images/defaultUser.png";
    return "user-photos/" + this.id + "/" + this.photos;
}
```

this is my thymleaf code, somewhere else it returned correct results for me but here the path for the photo I received is left with some "/ user / edit" parts. how to fix that
http://localhost:8080/ShopmeAdmin/users/edit/user-photos/13/cfe3d8d31bc1e89fb1d01.jpg

**i just want**: http://localhost:8080/ShopmeAdmin/user-photos/13/cfe3d8d31bc1e89fb1d01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, the string `"user-photos/"` does not have a leading slash (`/`) and therefore it will be interpreted as a relative path (relative to the current page location).

Assuming `ShopmeAdmin` is the root context of your application, then you need to add a leading slash to `user-photos/`:

```
return "/user-photos/" + this.id + "/" + this.photos;
```

Thymeleaf has a number of different ways to handle *relative* and *absolute* URLs in its [link URL](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) syntax, summarized here:

> Absolute URLs: http://www.thymeleaf.org
>
> Relative URLs, which can be:
>
> - Page-relative: user/login.html
> - Context-relative: /itemdetails?id=3 (context name in server will be added automatically)
> - Server-relative: ~/billing/processInvoice (allows calling URLs in another context (= application) in the same server.
> - Protocol-relative URLs: //code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Your current URL (without the leading slash) is relative to the current page (which I assume is the user edit page).

The new URL (with the leading slash) will be context-relative.

---

A couple of extra notes:

Protocol-relative URLs are out-of-date these days and should probably [no longer be used](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

I would recommend always using braces, for safety and clarity:

```java
if (id == null || photos == null) {
    return "/images/defaultUser.png";
}
```